# How to create a form input area that will only accept one answer using html

Tags: html, forms, validation, input, passwords

How, using HTML, can I create a text input or password input on a `<form>` that has a specific value eg : "apples" and the form will not submit unless the person entering their info into the form enters "apples" into that text (or password) input area?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the input control is required, and use a validation pattern consisting only of the word `apple`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function get(eId) {return document.getElementById(eId);};
        function verify(eId, eVal) {
            if (eVal !== get(eId).value) {
                alert('input must contain "' + eVal + '"!');
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        };
        function verifySubmit(eId,eVal) {
            if (verify(eId,eVal)) get(eId).parentNode.submit();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://google.com">
        <label>enter "apples": </label><input id="apple" type="text" onchange="verify(this.id,'apples');" /> 
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="verifySubmit('apple','apples');" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```